# Replacement of 100k potentiometer with mosfet

Tags: arduino, mosfet, voltage-regulator, pwm, dc-dc-converter

In this circuit i want to replace 100k potentiometer. As in this type of circuit the output voltage is set by rotating the knob manually so i just want to make it automatically by giving pwm signal to gate of MOSFET and MOSFET used as a variable resistor in place of 100k potentiometer. So i try to connect MOSFET in place of potentiometer it works but when i connect load it doesn't work so can someone please help me to find way to set it's voltage without rotating the knob..

[image]

Comment: How were you driving the MOSFET gate? What frequency and how did you connect the gate driver ground to this circuit. Were you using an n-channel or p-channel MOSFET? A schematic of what you actually built would help here.

Comment: Also what load did you connect and what is providing the input power to the XL6009 circuit?

Comment: Pin 5 is supposed to see slowly varying DC. Putting a PWM there will make the internal oscillator fight with your external signal. Options are 1. use mosfet in DC linear region (but most mosfets can't handle linear operation at higher current). 2. use a bjt. Either way, more info is required about your control circuit and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I drive the MOSFET with Arduino and Optocoupler i used  pmos  where i connect source to out+ and drain to 5 pin... And at 1k resistor left these connection open.

Comment: @indraneel i also used bjt it working properly without load but once i connect load then it not work properly..at input i connect 5volt adapter and at output 12 volt DC motor..

Comment: What output voltage range do you want? _"it not work properly..at input i connect 5volt adapter and at output 12 volt DC motor."_ - Are you trying to control the speed of a 12V motor? Which motor did you use?

Answer (score 0):

You could replace the 100K resistor with a special high voltage digital pot such as an [AD5293](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5293.pdf) (not particularly cheap).

The maximum output voltage would be 30V or so (abs. max is 35V), so you would have to add some kind of external overvoltage protection or shunt the digital pot with a resistor to limit the output voltage (which would make it nonlinear, but that could be fixed in software). You could also adjust the 1K resistor to limit the maximum.

The minimum output voltage is the reference voltage of about 1.25V.

If you need a higher settable output voltage you could muck around with resistor networks, with various trade-offs.

Comment: I need output voltage of 52

Comment: Great. And the minimum required adjustment range is?